# How to make "remember me" work if session expires when browser is closed?

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I set sessions to expire when browser closes in main `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        lifetime:       0
        auto_start:     true
```

Then I set "remember me" for login page as [described in documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/remember_me.html) and I'm getting logged out (when I restart browser) even if I check "remember me".

How to set a Symfony2 application to expire cookies when user closes browser, but persist them if one chooses to (by checking "remember me") upon login?

I'm using Symfony2-<strike>beta5</strike> <strike>RC1</strike> RC3.

Comment: That's normal for session variables.  They're only meant to last until the browser is closed.  What you need to use is cookies.

Comment: I know that I need to use cookies. This question is Symfony2 specific and I would like to know how to do it Symfony way without actually hacking it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when Beta 5 came out, but this post http://fossplanet.com/f6/%5Bsymfony-devs%5D-remember-me-authentication-67998/ leans towards it either not working, or not working right. Have you tried asking in the beta group?

Comment: No, not yet. I'll try to submit it as a bug on github and see what happens.