# Remember Me functionality not working in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, remember-me

I have implemented remember me functionality in Symfony2. When I log in with remember me box checked, cookie named "REMEMBERME" gets created. That cookie is also available if I close browser and open it after many hours. But when I load home page of my application, the cookie gets automatically deleted and I see no user logged in. Can anyone explain me the reason for cookie deletion?

```
remember_me:
          key:      qwerty
          lifetime: 604800
          path:     /
          domain:   ~
```

This is my security.yml file section

EDIT: I have still not found the solution to this question...

EDIT2: Now got new problem. The  REMEMBERME cookie does not get set at all. How to solve this??

SOLVED: see answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470994/how-to-make-remember-me-work-if-session-expires-when-browser-is-closed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

John.

I've the same issue as you do (or did), what I've found is that when I am (Symfony2 actually =) ) setting **REMEMBERME** cookie on line **101** at **/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/RememberMe/TokenBasedRememberMeService.php** file **$user->getPassword()** returns **NULL**, so cookie gets hash calculated with NULL password value.

What happening next, is when you returning to your site being fully confident that you will be automatically authenticated, Symfony begins to check your cookie at the **same file as above** but on **line 58** it founds that cookie **hash is not** the same as **it expects** and throws an exception('The cookie\'s hash is invalid.') internally catches it and proceeds somewhere.

So that is the case why in my case cookie doesn't work.

I haven't found a solution yet, but I will dig for it and may be I'm lucky.

Hope your issue is the same and solution will help us both.

**The Solution:**

When implementing eraseCredentials() which claims to be used to erase user sensitive data from UserInterface do not perform $this->password = null. I've made this mistake because I haven't being understanding its purpose. You can take a glance at [Symfony 2 Logout (UserInterface::eraseCredentials)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455398/symfony-2-logout-userinterfaceerasecredentials) for a little bit of explanation. So it serializes token object and we are in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have got a brand new problem. Now remember me cookie does not get set at all. :-( any idea??

Comment: Setting username to null also causes this problem.

Answer (score 13):

Although this question has already been answered, I would like to contribute a possible solution, if only for posterity and Google search referrals for this problem :)

"The issue is simple: a remembered used does not have the IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY role but only IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED to make a difference between a remembered user and a user who logged in"

Source: http://www.mail-archive.com/symfony-users@googlegroups.com/msg34021.html

What this means is that in your security configuration, you must make sure that for every ACL entry the IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED role is configured in addition to the IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY role.

For example:

```
#app/config/security.yml
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY,IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED] }
```

Comment: Good to know that IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Looks like trailing slash at the end of "/admin/" is also important.

Comment: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` and `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` don't need to be added together, they are a heirarchy (`FULLY > REMEMBERED > ANONYMOUSLY`). In this case, only `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the issue was that I did not use single quotation marks in the property **key** of **remember_me** section (security.yml).


**Change this**:

```
remember_me:
    key:      qwerty
    lifetime: 604800
    path:     /
    domain:   ~
```

**to this**:

```
remember_me:
    key:      'qwerty'
    lifetime: 604800
    path:     /
    domain:   ~
```

You can check it in the symfony documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/remember_me.html

Answer (score 0):

try to increase your session lifetime:
(config.yml)

```
  framework:
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        auto_start:     true
        lifetime:       604800
```

Comment: that is not the way to add remember me functionality.... and this also does not work after browser close and reopen

Comment: that is not the way to add remember me functionality, but it's for the cookies session lifetime. With my configuration the session is alive after browser restart. Sorry, i don't know what is different with your configuration.

Comment: This is bad, don't do it. It won't scale.

Comment: @bux _"the session is alive after browser restart"_. True, but we want session to be alive after browser restart only if the remember me option is checked, not always.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a wrong implementation of the supportsClass method of my *userProvider*, which in turn caused an exception in the *TokenBasedRememberMeService* class on line 43 (thrown by *getUserProvider*, and catched elsewhere, thus failing silently).
Digging in the path shown by Dmitry made me solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have implemented a custom Login Handler which was returning a `RedirectResponse` as per documentation. It turns out that that makes Symfony to bypass the standard login routine, and causing the `REMEMBERME` cookie not been created/stored.

I had to remove the Login Handler, implement a custom Login Listener with all needed logic.

You can see how to implement a Login Listener [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11180531/1333744)

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure your "remember_me" input in the login form does not have the **value** attribute:

This is **correct**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" />
```

But **this will not work**:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="" />
```

If you are using form_login, check also that remember_me is enabled in security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            # ...
            remember_me: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After investigation I found that :
`/vendor/symfony/doctrine-bridge/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php::loadUserByUsername()` requires to either have set the `property` field on your entity user provider or that your repository implements `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface` and has a method `loadUserByUsername()`.

I just added the property field like so :

```
providers:
    user_provider:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Symfony 4 and I had a similar problem, the `REMEMBERME` cookies was not set.

My issue was that I had a `value=""` set to the input type checkbox field.

So I changed from this

`<input type="checkbox" value="" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me">`

to this

`<input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me">`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the authenticators was overided with the method supportsRememberMe:

```
public function supportsRememberMe()
{
    return true; // change it to true
}
```