# Symfony2: Access encoded password from existing user

Tags: php, symfony

I want to access the encoded password in a controller or a service.

I can access it using Twig:

```
{{ app.user.password }} /* prints the encoded password. */
```

But when I am trying it from a controller, I'll get a null result:

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
$user->getPassword(); /* returns null */
```

Why can I access it using Twig, but not from the controller?

Comment: Do the other functions like `getId()` work with the `User` object you are getting from the `security.context` service or is it only the `getPassword()` method ?

Comment: Yes. `getId`, `getUsername`, `getCreatedAt` and also `getSalt` are working. Just `getPassword` returns NULL.

Comment: Does the `getPassword()` method actually **exist** in your `User` entity? With the information you provide this isn't for sure. if you had a public property `$password` that would explain why `{{ app.user.password }}` works but `$user->getPassword()` fails.

Comment: No. This wasn't the problem. But I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150262/symfony2-user-password-set-to-empty-after-running-this-method :)

Comment: Could you please add your findings with some description as an answer so we can have this issue marked as solved and other users can benefit aswell?