# Symfony/Doctrine tries to persist logged in user without a password

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Every time I call EntityManager::flush in any controller action to save any object, the ORM magic tries to also persist the user object from the currently logged in user if I had used any kind of Symfony security before. This object does not have any credentials stored because Symfony correctly called User::eraseCredentials. Do I have to remove the User manually from the EntityManager or do I miss some magic property in the Entity?

Comment: No magic required.  Something in your request flow is trying to update the user object.  Check to see if any of your setters are being called.

Comment: I  think you pointing me in the right direction. Indeed there is a ManyToOne pointing to the user object but it has no cascade property.  Symfonys eraseCredentilas function is a little bit misleading in the name choice. Thx a lot.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150262/symfony2-user-password-set-to-empty-after-running-this-method