# Programmatically logout current user

Tags: session, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.0

I am trying to programmatically logout the current user from inside a listener.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455398/symfony-2-logout-userinterfaceerasecredentials/8456507#8456507) that

```
$this->get('security.context')->setToken(null);
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate();
```

does the trick but then I can't call `$this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` anymore as the token is now `NULL`.

How can I log out the user but still let the application run normally?
I have calls to getUser() in my controller functions so I should set back the token to something corresponding to an non authenticated user. How can I do this?

Also, if there is a way to programmatically start a new session and set a flash message to inform the user he has been logged out, it would be awesome.

Comment: Dude. You're logged out now. How do you want to have user again from session? I see in your question some logical paradox.

Comment: I don't want to get the User, I want to be able to call the getUser() method without having a 500 internal error. When an unregistered user is using the website, I can call the getUser() because getToken() actually returns a valid token. After I set the token to NULL when programmatically logging the user off, my code is broken.

Comment: Why not do whatever it is you want to do with the user and then at the end of your function you kill the token/session to log them out?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$anonToken = new AnonymousToken('theTokensKey', 'anon.', array());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($anonToken);
```

first parameter is the token's key (i.e. '50cdf89882454')

Comment: Now its `security.token_storage` if anyone's interested.