# Symfony2: Functional Testing for Controllers with Session Variables Set in security.interactive_login Event

Tags: symfony

I have implemented a listener on the security.interactive_login event to set one session variable that is used all over my app, as advised in [Symfony2: After successful login event, perform set of actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180351/symfony2-after-successful-login-event-perform-set-of-actions). The problem is that the security.interactive_login event is not fired in functional tests (I guess this is logical since there is no actual interactive login). Given this restriction: How can I run functional tests with session variables set upon user login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u use basic authentication you can eventualy manualy fire event handler for testing but i think more proper way is to log in to app throu login form with submiting it with client - event listener should be fired that way.

Comment: Manually firing would be nice. I prefer doing tricks in tests to adapt to app instead of tricking the app to adapt to tests. Can you point me to a code sample where such firing is performed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlbertoGaona I mention manual firing event just to show that you can do it but proper way is to login with your test client. Im doing that successfuly myself for testing login events :) For manual firing events you can adapt code from [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php#L209).

Comment: one more thing - this dispatcher is a service in container named 'event_dispatcher'

Comment: Throwing away the basic authentication does the trick. My test looks awful, though

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring detail on the workaround:

In the functional test case I changed

```
$client = static::createClient(array(), array(
    'PHP_AUTH_USER'=>'alberto'
    ,'PHP_AUTH_PW'=>'********'
    )
);
```

For

```
$client = static::createClient();
$crawler = $client->request('GET','/secured/login');
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Aceptar')->form();
$form['_username'] = 'alberto';
$form['_password'] = '********';
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```