# Add log to user login/logout Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have a simple SecurityBundle following the [symfony.com](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html) documentation I've created:

- UserRepository which implements `UserProviderInterface`
- UserEntity which implements `UserInterface` and `EquatableInterface`
- SecurityController which has a `loginAction`
- setup routing with login, login_check, logout routes
- setup my firewall settings

---

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('MySecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error' => $error,
    ));
}
```

Everything is OK, but i need add a logger for every action by user, example: `USER:username, DO:erase file XXXXX, AT:2013-08-08.15-03-43` the problem is i dont have control in the logout, login action because the firewall catch these and i dont know how to modify

Comment: Check this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) - it would help you to understand where you should inject your code and when login/logout event occurs

Comment: Thanks, could not find the place where they explain this topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login event can be catched by `security.interactive_login` event. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180351/symfony2-after-successful-login-event-perform-set-of-actions).

For logout needs to specify your own `success_handler` in logout firewall. [Read here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/iJ9Kq72aTgM). The same can be done for a login.

```
firewalls:
    main:
        form_login:
            failure_handler: mybundle.security.handler.failure
            success_handler:mybundle.security.handler.success
        logout:
            success_handler: mybundle.security.handler.logout
```

Comment: One link is dead and the other just links to another SO question. This answer doesn't really have any info