# Symfony 2 : Security Configuration : Login and logout handlers

Tags: symfony

Using Symfony 2, I am looking for more information about the handlers that you can define in the security configuration file `app/config/security.yml` ([official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)). The documentation doesn't give any informations about handlers. Here is an extract of the security file :

```
# app/config/security.yml

security:        
    ...

    firewalls:                            
            somename:
        
                form_login:
                    ...
    
                    # login failure redirecting options (read further below)
                    failure_path:    /foo
                    failure_forward: false
                    failure_path_parameter: _failure_path
                    failure_handler: some.service.id
                    success_handler: some.service.id
    
    
                logout:
                    path:   /logout
                    target: /
                    invalidate_session: false
                    delete_cookies:
                        a: { path: null, domain: null }
                        b: { path: null, domain: null }
                    handlers: [some.service.id, another.service.id]
                    success_handler: some.service.id
                anonymous: ~
```

In both *form_login* ang *logout* part there is a `success_handler` field. Moreover, for *logout* part you can define several handlers using `handlers` field.

I have two questions :

1. If I define a `succes_handler` service (using for example AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface or LogoutHandlerInterface), will it overide the default success handler provided in the framework ?
2. For the *logout* part of the configuration, how work the `handlers`field ?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28400632/symfony-2-after-login-do-some-extra-job/28403893#28403893) answer. Hope this help

Comment: @Matteo Thank you. I have read a lot of posts on the subject but I could not find any precise information . What I would like to know is if I define my own succes handler, will it override the default one or do I need to extend the default one as described in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918617/symfony2-extending-defaultauthenticationsuccesshandler) ?

Comment: I haven't try but i think no

Comment: OK I will try to see.

Comment: To override the default success handler i think that you should add this to your security.yml 

parameters:
 
    security.authentication.success_handler.class: Xxx\YourBundle\Component\OverSf2\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
 
services:
 
    security.authentication.success_handler:
        class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  ['@router', '@security.user.entity_manager']

Comment: @Hajri I want to avoid overriding the default success handler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For information, in *logout* part of `app/config/security.yml` :

`handlers: [some.service.id, another.service.id]` => Here you have to define services implementing `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutHandlerInterface`. Theses handles do not need to return a response. In my case I created a simple handler that creates a flash message on logout.

`success_handler: some.service.id` => Here you have to define a service implementing => `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Logout\LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface`. This handler have to return a response. This handler is called by the constructor of `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\LogoutListener` (firewall listener).

Comment: to answer your 1st question: yes by creating custom `succes_handler` service you will overwrite the default one. however the default logout handler is `DefaultLogoutSuccessHandler` and all it does is, it redirects to `logout target` route so its safe to overwrite this.
mark this response as correct answer please

Answer (score 0):

I tried with success the next solution 
https://gist.github.com/marydn/8061424
Seems to be what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you. Yes that's what I want to do. I have no problem on how to do this. I wanted to be sure that using this method I would not override the default success handler provided in Symfony (as the documentation is not really helpful).

Comment: To be more specific I want to add a flash message on login/logout event, so I don't want to affect the response. For login, an event listener can be used (listening to security.interactive_login) and for logout a logout succes handler implementing LogoutHandlerInterface (as there is no logout event). This interface permits to avoid returning a response (by opposition to LogoutSuccessHandlerInterface).