# Symfony 3 - Last logged date

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

Trying to put the database date of the last login user, but completely do not know how to do it.

Please help and thank you in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: After successful login event, perform set of actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180351/symfony2-after-successful-login-event-perform-set-of-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using FOSBundle, this is done for you automatically. For example, here is a typical debug log after just logging in:

```
[2016-06-26 19:57:45] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE fos_user SET last_login = ? WHERE id = ? ["2016-06-26 19:57:45",3] []
```

You didn't indicate in your post what bundle you are using, or what exactly you are trying to do...