# Symfony service on Login action like onKernelRequest

Tags: symfony, service, authentication

One simple question please.

I have a service that it's launched **onKernelRequest**, but it doesn't work when an user is loggin in my app.

It's possible setup a service that it will be launched on login action?

This is my actual service:

```
cc.database_switcher:
    class:      XXXXX\EventListener\DatabaseSwitcherEventListener
    arguments:  [@request, @doctrine.dbal.default_connection, @logger]
    scope:      request
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

This service don't work con loggin action.

Comment: You can check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/11180531/1203821

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2: After successful login event, perform set of actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11180351/symfony2-after-successful-login-event-perform-set-of-actions)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface` and declare it as service. Implement all the logic you want in `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.
Then define `success_handler` option in your `security.yml` in `form_login` area:

```
form_login:
    ...
    ...
    success_handler: your_own_on_success_login_handler
```

[An example](http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/)